# Dynamic type hinting for dynamically created classes

Tags: python, type-hinting

I would like to create type hinting for dynamically created classes. I have the following code, but it does not work for type hinting.

```py
from typing import Type, cast, Unpack, Annotated, TypedDict, Callable

class Base:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        pass

def create() -> Type[Base]:
    class TD(TypedDict):
        first: int
        second: str
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Unpack[TD]):
        setattr(self, 'a', kwargs['first'])
        setattr(self, 'b', kwargs['second'])

    __init__.__annotations__.update({'kwargs': Unpack[TD]})

    return type('Child', (Base,), {'__init__': __init__, '__annotations__': {'a': int, 'b': str}})

Child = create()

c = Child(first=1, second='Hello')
print(c.b) # 'Hello'

print(Child.__annotations__) # {'a': int, 'b': str}
print(Child.__init__.__annotations__['kwargs'].__args__[0].__annotations__) # {'first': int, 'second': str}
```

Am I missing something or is this just not possible?

Comment: Type hinting is static. Its the opposite of dynamic, it's not possible.

Comment: I was afarid of this :( Thank you!

Comment: Annotations != type hints. Type hints are a _small subset_ of annotations that follow a known schema which (static) type checkers can understand and deduce the types of expression from. If you want to do a sort of type checking using the runtime value of `__annotations__`, you could try using a runtime type checker, like beartype

Comment: If your dynamically created classes are sufficiently simple / similar, you might be able to use a [protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/).